# How can I replace string using NSRegularExpression in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, swift, nsregularexpression

For example the `regular` expression is :

```
A(B)C
```

A,B,C all represent some string.I want all the string matches A(B)C replacing by B.

If the `NSString` is AABCAABCBBABC:

The answear will be ABABBBB.How to do that? Thank you.

I give a more specific example:

```
<script\stype="text/javascript"[\s\S]*?(http://[\s\S]*?)'[\s\S]*?</script>
```

The answer is some script mathes and `http://` url matches .
I want to use each `http://` url matches to replace each script matches. Did  I explain it clearly?

Comment: I guess the regex must be "AbbBbbCbb", and replacement "Bbb". Have a look: https://regex101.com/r/hH1tY5/1

Comment: @leizh00701, still not cleared. you may explain with what is input and what is your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution can be using `stringByReplacingMatchesInString`:

```
NSString *strText = @"AABCAABCBBABC";
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regexExpression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"ABC" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *strModifiedText = [regexExpression stringByReplacingMatchesInString:strText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [strText length]) withTemplate:@"B"];
NSLog(@"%@", strModifiedText);
```

Another solution can be using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` :

```
strText = [strText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ABC" withString:@"B"];
```

Comment: No,withTemplate:@"B" is not what I what .The template B is all represent a string getting from the regex matching answer